# Does AdWords support polite loading or backup images?

Tags: advertising, html5, google-ads

I"m new to creating HTML5 display ads and I don't know whether AdWords supports polite loading or backup images.

When we upload and test our ads, there is some lag where there is no ad for a moment.  We would really like some placeholder to appear during this time to remedy this if possible.

Comment: I've edited your question based on what I think you mean.   I think you want some backup image to show before your ad gets loaded, correct?